# Configuring ECL for the "Everyone" Group

Tags: configuration, content-manager, ecl, media-manager

The ExternalContentLibrary.xml configuration has an `<EnableUpload>` node where we can add SDL Tridion groups.

I'm able to add the "Everyone" group, which I found by hovering over publication authorization settings in the CME.

**Quick questions**:

- Does the "Everyone" group always have the same identifier (e.g. `tcm:0-1-65568`)?
- How else would you find the Everyone ID (CME or code if you prefer)?
- I understand this is a setting that's not visible in the CME as a Group. Is it really a group behind-the-scenes (to the Content Manager)?

Comment: Nice find, should be added to the ECL config chapter in the manual.

Comment: Good point, I left a comment on the documentation portal. Care to submit an SDL Tridion Idea to make this configurable/portable in the CME (maybe AppData like some of XPM's settings)?

Comment: If it is a fixed id it does not have to be configurable? Or do you want to make it visible by config?

Comment: I think choosing the "Everyone" group should be configurable. At the minimum the docs have my comment on what its tcm-id (`tcm:0-1-65568`). Low priority, but maybe we could get it in an XML comment in `ExternalContentLibrary.xml`. Rather than "visible by config" I'm thinking "configuring it *visibly*" as in the CME. Right-click on Mount Point > Security > then pick groups. What do you think?

Comment: Technically speaking this configuration value belongs to the Media Manager connector, it is not generic ECL functionality. And yes, this area could be improved, but as it is a workaround for limitations in the Media Manager API I would rather see this go away all together instead of it being improved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the "Everyone" group always have the same identifier (e.g. tcm:0-1-65568)?

**Yes, this is the default id assigned during Tridion installation**

How else would you find the Everyone ID (CME or code if you prefer)?

**You can query the Tridion_cm database in the TRUSTEES table (this will always be id=1)**

I understand this is a setting that's not visible in the CME as a Group. Is it really a group behind-the-scenes (to the Content Manager)?

**If you really want the EVERYONE group to show in the CME, then change IS_PREDEFINED value to 0
(MTSUSER is hidden as well because IS_PREDEFINED = 1)**

Comment: Interesting, I don't think we'll need to show the group, but I was curious if it was just a "setting." +1 and I'm accepting, though I am obligated to mention we shouldn't change the database without good cause (like Support telling us to).